# NumPy sum one array based on values in another array for each matching element in 3rd array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, one containing values and one containing each values category.

```
values=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
valcats=np.array([101,301,201,201,102,302,302,202,102,301])
```

I have another array containing the unique categories I'd like to sum across.

```
categories=np.array([101,102,201,202,301,302])
```

My issue is that I will be running this same summing process a few billion times and every microsecond matters.

My current implementation is as follows.

```
catsums=[]
for x in categories:
    catsums.append(np.sum(values[np.where(valcats==x)]))
```

The resulting catsums should be:

```
[1, 14, 7, 8, 12, 13]
```

My current run time is about 5 µs. I am somewhat new still to Python and was hoping to find a fast solution by potentially combining the first two arrays or lamdba or something cool I don't even know about.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: what is your expected output considering the example you gave?

Comment: Added to text, thanks for pointing out that oversight!

Comment: upvoted your question , You have 15 rep now ,feel free to upvote and accept @piRSquared answer

Answer (score 9):

You can use `searchsorted` and `bincount` -

```
np.bincount(np.searchsorted(categories, valcats), values)
```

Comment: What would you add if the categories array wasn't already sorted?

Comment: @piRSquared I would sort it and then feed it into the solution.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of passing the `sorter` parameter... , `sorter=categories.argsort()`

Comment: @piRSquared There's a lot of overhead involved. Don't think its worth it for a case like this.

Comment: @hrschbck You can do : `ids = np.searchsorted(categories, valcats)` and then `df.groupby('ids')['values'].max().values`, if you were looking for an *easy* way. For `sum`, you would reuse `ids` : `np.bincount(ids, values)`.

Answer (score 8):

@Divakar just posted a very good answer.  If you already have the array of categories defined, I'd use @Divakar's answer.  If you don't have unique values already define, I'd use mine.

---

I'd use [**`pd.factorize`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to factorize the categories.  Then use [**`np.bincount`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) with `weights` parameter set to be the `values` array

```
f, u = pd.factorize(valcats)
np.bincount(f, values).astype(values.dtype)

array([ 1, 12,  7, 14, 13,  8])
```

`pd.factorize` also produces the unique values in the `u` variable.  We can line up the results with `u` to see that we've arrived at the correct solution.

```
np.column_stack([u, np.bincount(f, values).astype(values.dtype)])

array([[101,   1],
       [301,  12],
       [201,   7],
       [102,  14],
       [302,  13],
       [202,   8]])
```

You can make this more obvious using a `pd.Series`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(valcats)
pd.Series(np.bincount(f, values).astype(values.dtype), u)

101     1
301    12
201     7
102    14
302    13
202     8
dtype: int64
```

---

**Why** `pd.factorize` **and not** `np.unique`**?**

We could have done this equivalently with

```
 u, f = np.unique(valcats, return_inverse=True)
```

But, `np.unique` sorts the values and that runs in `nlogn` time.  On the other hand `pd.factorize` does not sort and runs in linear time.  For larger data sets, `pd.factorize` will dominate performance.

Comment: Nice solution ~ +1

Comment: Thank you @Wen (-:

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation  !

Comment: That is a new question... and I have an answer for you.