# Sum of Guassian by Multiple regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, linear-regression

I have 16 guassian curves which I have to fit with one guassian curve. I was unable to imply the sum of guassian(multiple regression) in python.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=np.array([3750.0, -250.0, 6750.0, 2750.0, -2050.0, 6350.0, 1550.0, -4050.0, 5750.0, 150.0, -6250.0, 4950.0, -1450.0, -8650.0, 3950.0, -3250.0])
v1=np.array( [2.5470357695283954, 0.1937004980283323, 0.43831655553839766, 6.07645636407398, 0.6331239135554633, 0.969937308645575, 13.38133838752005, 1.3226417845166933, 1.5531178254607325, 27.599625693090765, 2.031000233294804, 1.635762971986014, 53.83073800155456, 2.0719664311822843, 0.0, 100.0])
x=[]
s=[]
v5=9.9e2
for j in range(0,len(a)):
    for i in range(-1500,1500):
        v11=a[j]+i
        x.append(v11)
        z=np.exp((-4*np.log(2)*((v11-a[j])/(v5))**2))*((4.5*np.log(2)/(np.pi))**0.5)
        s.append(z*v1[j])
plt.plot(x,s,'--r',)
plt.stem(a,v1)
```

Which generates the following plot (with the problem circled):

[image]

Instead of the desired output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: You should clarify what is the expected output. The center, std and height of each gaussian is _hard coded_ in am v1 and v5, the overlapping is not a plot artifact but the result of plotting these gaussians together. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: @xg.plt.py i have uploaded a figure [expected output] kindly have a look at it,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your code shows this overlapping because you are not summing the 16 gaussians but instead creating an array containing `[x1_g1,x1_g1,...,x3000_g1,x1_g2,...,x3000_g16]` and the same for `s`. It is a 1d array containing the 3000 x values of the first gaussian, then the 3000 x values of the second gaussian and so on. But they are not added. Thus, the plot shows the 16 independent gaussians instead of the sum which is the desired output.

In the actual code, the x values of each gaussian are different (going -1500 and +1500 around its center) which makes adding the 16 gaussians more complicated.

If we consider only the first 2 gaussians for instance, centered at 3750 and -250, the values appended in x from the first gaussian go from 2250 to 5250 in steps of 1, as well as their images in `s` which are s(2250)... Afterwards, the values of the second gaussian (x between -1750 and 1250) are appended (not added), which will result in an x list like that:

```
x = [2250,2251,<in steps of 1>,5249,5250,-1750,-1749,<in steps of 1>,1250]
```

And `s` is a list where each position contains the image of the same position in `x`. Strating from this format, getting the final output which is the sum of the gaussians id difficult, because we wolud have to check for equivalent values of x, and sum their contributions...

However, if instead we **always** evaluated the gaussians at the same positions (in the exemple between -1750 and 5250 in steps of 1), we will have much more values stored, and most of them will be zero, but adding them will be straightforward.

---

## Half-way vectorization

One option similar to the code in the question is the following:

```
a = np.array([3750.0, -250.0, 6750.0, 2750.0, -2050.0, 6350.0, 1550.0, -4050.0, 5750.0, 150.0, -6250.0, 4950.0, -1450.0, -8650.0, 3950.0, -3250.0])
v1 = np.array( [2.5470357695283954, 0.1937004980283323, 0.43831655553839766, 6.07645636407398, 0.6331239135554633, 0.969937308645575, 13.38133838752005, 1.3226417845166933, 1.5531178254607325, 27.599625693090765, 2.031000233294804, 1.635762971986014, 53.83073800155456, 2.0719664311822843, 0.0, 100.0])
v5 = 9.9e2

xrange = np.arange(a.min()-1500,a.max()+1500) 
# This generates an array between the minimum of a minus 1500 and the maximum of a 
# plus 1500. This way, all the values in the old x list are contained in ths array
# Therefore, it becomes really easy to sum the contribution of each gaussian, 
# because only an element-wise sum is needed.
s = np.zeros(len(xrange))

for j,aj in enumerate(a):
    z = np.exp((-4*np.log(2)*((xrange-aj)/(v5))**2))*((4.5*np.log(2)/(np.pi))**0.5)
    s += z*v1[j]

plt.plot(xrange,s,'--r')
plt.stem(a,v1)
```

The output plot is the same as for the completely vectorized solution.

---

## Completely vectorized solution

One simple solution is to define a unique xrange for all 16 gaussians, then calculate `s` for each of them (on the same x values) and finally sum over the 16 gaussians:

```
a = np.array([3750.0, -250.0, 6750.0, 2750.0, -2050.0, 6350.0, 1550.0, -4050.0, 5750.0, 150.0, -6250.0, 4950.0, -1450.0, -8650.0, 3950.0, -3250.0])
v1 = np.array( [2.5470357695283954, 0.1937004980283323, 0.43831655553839766, 6.07645636407398, 0.6331239135554633, 0.969937308645575, 13.38133838752005, 1.3226417845166933, 1.5531178254607325, 27.599625693090765, 2.031000233294804, 1.635762971986014, 53.83073800155456, 2.0719664311822843, 0.0, 100.0])
v5 = 9.9e2

xrange = np.arange(a.min()-1500,a.max()+1500)

z = np.exp((-4*np.log(2)*((xrange-a.reshape((len(a),1)))/(v5))**2))*((4.5*np.log(2)/(np.pi))**0.5)
s = z*v1.reshape((len(a),1))

plt.plot(xrange,s.sum(axis=0),'--r')
plt.stem(a,v1)
```

Note that I have removed the 2 nested loops using numpy.

The loop over `range(-1500,1500)` can be avoided defining `i=np.arange(-1500,1500)` instead of the `for i in ...` and leaving the rest of the code untouched (only indentation has to be updated). Thet is because numpy operated element-wise over the arrays.

The second loop is a bit trickier than that. The `a` and `v1` arrays are reshaped to a 2d array, in order to generate a `z` with the shape (16,len(xrange)). Thas is why combining an array xrange of length muxh larger than 16 with `a` does not raise any error of dimensions not matching, because one is the 1st dimension and the other the second.

The code above generates the following plot:

[image: sum of gaussians]

---

## Groupby solution

There is also the option of working with the same code to generate `x` and `s` and afterwards, plot every unique value of `x` (the same value of x can be found in `x[i1],x[i2],x[i3]`) versus `s[i1]+s[i2]+s[i3]`.

This can be done adding the following code after the loops:

```
x,s = np.array(x),np.array(s)
ind = np.argsort(x)
x,s = x[ind],s[ind]
unique_x = np.unique(x)
catsums=[]
for k in unique_x:
    catsums.append(np.sum(s[np.where(x==k)]))

plt.plot(u,catsums,'--r')
plt.stem(a,v1)
```

This groupby can also be vectorized using numpy or pandas as it is explained in this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45267375/2504700)

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding! Is everything explained clearly?

Comment: No , i am new to coding python, i am trying to understand it but ur coding is too difficult for me..

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask then. Why a unique xrange is needed is clear?

Comment: no i cant.. this is new to me.. i have ever seen this [xrange = np.arange(a.min()-1500,a.max()+1500)] command before ..

Comment: The reshaping is a trick to vectorize the loop. In the loops ,what was done was evaluating s(x;a) for each value of x and each value of a. Numpy can evaluate f(**x**) where **x** is an array, returning directly the array result of evaluating f(x) for every element of **x**. Therefore, if we construct a matrix liek a table where the column is x and the row is a, _all_ the operatinos can be executed at once with numpy. Reshaping tells numpy to return this matrix, that is why the shape of z is _(16, len(xrange))_